# what does ground mean in "a lot of **ground**"?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/J0FDlPkWGDs?t=675) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> So we use this a lot of the times when we're talking about body parts, tools, or instruments;
>   things that help you do things.
>   Okay, so we've covered a lot of **ground** here.

cambridge dictionary gives this explanation about ground

> the surface of the earth or of a piece of land
>
> to connect a piece of electrical equipment to the ground with a wire

none of them fits this case.

what does ground mean in "a lot of **ground**"?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you so much. Would you please move your comments to answer? 
I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common "spatial" metaphoric usage, similar to *The negotiations **covered** a broad **area***, or *His talk touched on a **range** of subjects*.

In OP's exact context, figurative ***ground*** refers to the ***range*** of topics discussed...

> *We've covered **a lot of ground***
>    =
>    *We've talked about **a wide range of subjects***